# Auto post on linkedin giving error

Tags: php, laravel, linkedin-api

When i am trying to auto post on linkedin using Oauth.php it's giving error

> 401
>    1497331341266
>     VCWVDSHNV2
>     0
>     [unauthorized]. The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. consumerKey: 81h62txugfyqtk

Please give me solution I am trying this from very long time.

Comment: Please read the [mcve] before asking. Without enough code example and explaining what have you tried so far, it is very difficult to answer the question

Comment: check your credentials and redirect uri